# Bundling PyQwt with py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I have a standard setup script for py2exe with which I bundle PyQt-based applications into Windows .exe files.

Today I tried a simple script that uses the PyQwt module, and it doesn't seem to work. py2exe runs alright, but when I execute the .exe it creates, it dumps the following into a log file and doesn't run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qwt_test.pyw", line 5, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "PyQt4\Qwt5\__init__.pyo", line 32, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading PyQt4\Qwt5\Qwt.pyd
```

When I look in `PyQt4\Qwt5\` in the `build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.5` directory, `Qwt.pyd` is definitely there.

I can't seem to find anything useful online regarding this error. What could cause it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

py2exe is not the only way, and maybe not the best way, to put together exe files for Python apps -- in particular, it hardly if at all supports pyqt. Please, I beseech you, check out [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which DOES know about PyQt (and Linux, and Mac, should you care...) -- just make sure you use the SVN head checkout, not the "released" version, which at this time is seriously out of date (an issue that's hopefully going away soon...).

Comment: Alex, py2exe works just fine with PyQt for me, it's only the PyQwt part that's causing problems. Why do you prefer PyInstaller? To me it seems less supported, less updated and a bit archaic to use.

Comment: Used to be (less supported &c) but that's changed recently -- see http://www.pycon.it/conference/talks/distribuire-programmi-python-con-pyinstaller and http://www.pycon.it/static/stuff/slides/distribuire-programmi-python-con-pyinstaller.pdf (don't worry about the URL, it's in English;-). Once you svn co http://svn.pyinstaller.org/trunk pyinstaller, pyinstaller/doc/CHANGES.txt lists the many changes since 1.3. I just hope they make a release soon!-)

Comment: I've worked with PyInstaller before, and in fact it managed to pack the PyQwt app correctly. But I was always disappointed at the lack of support. Having to download from SVN is not a sign of a healthy project. I hope you're right though and they'll improve it soon.

Comment: Hey, you've got some of the current developers' emails now (the bunch of Italian programmers mentioned at the above URLs) -- why not let them know directly, the more users they hear it from, the likelier they are to decide to release (& _maybe_ document;-) instead of continuing to pile on features...!-)

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

1. Try playing with the py2xe `bundle_files options` (3, 2, 1) (especially if you put them all in one big library zip, some dlls don't like that).
2. Make sure a copy of `msvcp71.dll` exists under windows\system32 or in the directory of your executable.
3. Try excluding the dll explicitely (add Qwt.pyd to the `dll_excludes` option and (after building) copy Qwt.pyd (and _Qwt.pyd if it exists) to your executable path.