# Bundling PyQwt with py2exe

Tags: py2exe

unable to find dll when i tried to build exe with py2exe.
My script contains 
from Qwt import *

if i remove this line every thing working find.
Plz help me

Comment: Could you show some code (your py2exe script) and what the error is (i.e. which DLL is it failing with - a Qwt DLL or something like an  msvc*.dll)?

Answer (score 0):

See [Bundling PyQwt with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899658/bundling-pyqwt-with-py2exe)

Also you could try using something else for making executable, for example [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).